# How to separate an input sting with several keys and values in JS?

Tags: javascript

I initially had an input string of the form

"Average Event Size: 0.000 KB - Orbit counter: 1986836 - N. L1A waiting (OFIFO): 0 - FED id configured: 654 (0x28e) - JTAG Access mode: VME ======================================================================= 
Words in SPY fifo: 219716 Events in OFIFO: 2000 Last Bunch triggered : 0x1 L1A counter: 4027452 "

I got the keys and values from it using the following code:

```
infoStringArray = infoString.split("\n");
    for (var i = 0, size = infoStringArray.length; i < size ; i++){
        if (infoStringArray[i].search(":") != -1){
            var keyvalue = infoStringArray[i].split(":");
            var key = keyvalue[0].trim();
            if (key[0] == "-"){
                key = key.substring(2);
            }
            board_data.boarddata[key] = keyvalue[1].trim();
        }
    }
```

This was easy because the different keys and values are separated by '-'. However, now I am given a string of the form:

"SRP channel clock: OK DCC/TCC channel clock: OK TTC 40MHz clock: OK RC state: Idle SRP state: WaiForL1AEnable Card configured: yes Out of sync: no "

The only separator is space but it is also used in the names of some keys. I am looking for ideas about how to do this.

Comment: If separator was a newline (\n), it would be easy, but being a whitespace... i find it difficult to achieve.

Comment: You can't without giving us more rules.  eg. how do we know if the first value is `219716 Events` or is `219716`, computers use logic, and we have none here.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works on the assumption that the value will always be a single word:

```js
var input = "SRP channel clock: OK DCC/TCC channel clock: OK TTC 40MHz clock: OK RC state: Idle SRP state: WaiForL1AEnable Card configured: yes Out of sync: no ";

// Initial split operation
var ary = input.split(":");

for(var i = 0; i < ary.length-1; i++){
  // Remove leading or trailing spaces
  ary[i] = ary[i].trim();
  
  // If we are on a value
  if(i % 2 !== 0){
    // Split the value portion (string) into a temporary array
    var tempAry = ary[i].split(/\s/);
    
    // Set the value to only the first index of the temporary array and then
    // drop that value from the temporary array so it doesn't wind up being
    // part of the remaining string because that is now the next key.
    ary[i] = tempAry.shift();
    
    // Reassemble the remaining words
    var x = tempAry.join(" ");
    
    // Insert the next proper key into the array at the next index
    ary.splice([i+1],0,x);
  }

}

// Now that the keys and values have been separated correctly,
// reassemble them into a final object
var result = {}
for(var x = 0; x < ary.length; x++){
  // If we are on a key, write a new object property and its corresponding value
  (x % 2 === 0) ? result[ary[x]] = ary[x+1] : "";
}

// Show the final object:
console.log(result);
```

Comment: your solution is over complicated

Comment: @MarcinMalinowski It is certainly more code than your answer, but it works and is well explained. Not a reason for a down vote.

Comment: in the last key you code adds extra spaces to the "no" value.

Comment: @MarcinMalinowski Now, you are just splitting hairs. Still not a reason for a down vote.

Comment: it is also not a good reason to down vote a correct answer only because your answer has been downvoted lol

Comment: down voting a buggy and complicated code is what one should do

Answer (score 0):

```js
var infoString = "SRP channel clock: OK DCC/TCC channel clock: OK TTC 40MHz clock: OK RC state: Idle SRP state: WaiForL1AEnable Card configured: yes Out of sync: no";

infoString.replace(/(.*?):\s(\w+)[\s-]*/g, function (match, key, value) { 
  console.log(key, '-', value);
});
```